# Node.js win32-api Get and set window title having window process id

Tags: node.js, winapi

How can i achieve this what i wrote in topic? I have access to win32-api in my node app and i know this window processID which i want to change. I know that functions `EnumWindows()` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` would be usefull in this but i dont know even what to pass as parameters to `EnumWindows()` and what this function will return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure your window is top-level when using [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows).

The function has 2 parameters:

> lpEnumFunc
>
> Type: **WNDENUMPROC**
>
> A pointer to an application-defined callback function. For more
>   information, see [`EnumWindowsProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633498(v%3Dvs.85)).
>
> lParam
>
> Type: **LPARAM**
>
> An application-defined value to be passed to the callback function.(you can pass the process id to it)

You could call the `GetWindowThreadProcessId` in the callback `EnumWindowsProc` and compare with the process id for each window found.

Here is the sample in C++:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD *pid = (DWORD*)(lParam);
    DWORD processId;
    if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processId) && processId == *pid)
    {
        WCHAR Title[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
        GetWindowTextW(hwnd,Title, MAX_PATH);
        wprintf(L"Title : %s\n", Title);
        SetWindowTextW(hwnd, L"TestTitle");
        return FALSE; //end enumerating;
    }
    // Continue enumerating
    return TRUE;
}
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    DWORD pid = 11244;//set the process id you have.
    BOOL bResult = EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc,(LPARAM)&pid);
    return 0;
}
```

And for using `EnumWindowsProc` callback in node.js, you could refer to this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28127046/10611792) .

Comment: Hi @Dawid Pstrak, does this answer your question? Please feel free to contact me if you have any issues.